# Return XML Nodes in a particular order

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am querying an `XMLDocument` using `SelectNodes()`. However, I need the return of the query to be in a particular order based on an element contained inside the nodes being queried.  I don't see any way to do this with `SelectNodes` method. How can this be accomplished?

Here is my query:

```
XmlNodeList booksNodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//BOOKS");
```

I want to order this by publication date which is an element contained inside the `<BOOKS>` node.

Comment: What language would this be in? Java? C#? Database server with XML capabilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try LINQ against your collection of nodes like here:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<XmlNode> booksNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//BOOKS")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .OrderBy(node => node.Attributes["title"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume you're using C# based on the class names. Anyway, if you're at libery to use XSLT in there, you'll find there's a handy [`<xsl:sort>`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_sort.asp) element in there. Maybe you can apply the XSLT on your document and filter out those nodes you need, already sorted by the right element.

Otherwise, I suppose you'd need to sort the resulting list using some custom compare method that delves to the contained element.

I'm not a C# developer (Java guy) so I wouldn't know how that's done, but I believe you lucky devils get all sorts of cool closure and delegate support, so that shouldn't be too hard :D